# How to query a in memory data base?

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I have a in memory data base created by using the disconnected class. I have populated the data table, now I want to query to select particular rows from the data table. What is the most simple way?

Comment: which kind of programming language? what kind of inmemory database?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, anyway I'm using C#, designed the database using the disconnected class e.i. data table obj to create the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use C# and `DataTable` you can query it for example like:

```
private void GetRowsByFilter()
{
    DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables["Orders"];
    // Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date.
    string expression;
    expression = "Date > #1/1/00#";
    DataRow[] foundRows;

    // Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
    foundRows = table.Select(expression);

    // Print column 0 of each returned row.
    for(int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foundRows[i][0]);
    }
}
```

Example from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/det4aw50.aspx

You can also use LINQ to query the collection by `DataTable.AsEnumarable`

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you could please give me some sample code for linq too. I have a single table named StudentInfo with just two columns e.i. studentname & studentroll. i would like to fetch the row with particular roll. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var rows = StudentInfo.AsEnumerable().Where(info => info.Field<string>("studentroll") == "roll")` for example